# Who is Abra's mother?

Tags: east-of-eden

In the 1955 film *East of Eden*, who is Abra's mother?

We know her father Will Hamilton is a business friend/partner to Adam Trask (Raymond Massey), and their children, daughter Abra (Julie Harris) and son Aron Trask (Richard Davalos), have a relationship. Cal Trask (James Dean) is "bad" as stated through father Adam, as is his (later admitted) mother Kate (Jo Van Fleet). Abra on the Ferris Wheel describes herself as "bad" also.

Abra's mother is unmentioned, and there is no credit upon my review of the film in IMDb. I have not read the novel, from which only the ending half is portrayed in the film.

Knowing that Cal and Aron are hidden sons of Kate, could there be the possibility that Abra is also her daughter through Will? Is there the possibility of an incestuous relationship in the Aron / Abra / Cal relationship? Is it hinted at in the novel, somewhat in this film, or in the miniseries of 1981?

Comment: In the novel Abra is not Hamilton's daughter. She is the daughter of a corrupt county supervisor and her surname is Bacon.

Comment: So, they conflated the character for her in the film, or did I mistake her relationship to Will?

Comment: No idea. I've never seen the movie or read the novel. I just looked it up online. Looking through the script it shows her first appearing with Mr. Hamilton but she doesn't call him father anywhere that I can see.

Comment: I remember Adam saying to Will, "our children", I think, just before the ice house scene. I need to re-watch that interchange.

Comment: Forget my earlier assertion about "our children"; it's not there or close surrounding scene. Abra does call him "Mr. Hamilton", which is weird except under some bombastic paternalistic demands, like Baron might have to call his father "King" or somesuch. But this "corrupt county supervisor" might add some other flavor along the same lines.